# Difference between method and protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, methods, delegates, protocols

In classC, both method and protocol can call the functions, what's the difference between them? Does method cost more memory?

One thing I know is that protocol can include functions of different class.

```
protocol MyDelegate{
    func printInA()
}

class ClassA: UITableViewController, MyDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func printInA(){
        print("I'm in ClassA")
    }
}

class ClassB: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func pringInB(){
        print("I'm in ClassB")
    }
}


class ClassC: UITableViewController {

    var myInstance:MyDelegate = ClassA()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myInstance.printInA()

        let k = ClassB()
        k.pringInB()
    } 

}
```

Comment: Given your description may I politely suggest that you spend time reading the [Methods chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html) and the [Protocols chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) of the Swift book.

Comment: You should also adjust to using standard naming conventions. Class, struct, enum, and protocol names should start with uppercase letters. Variables, functions, and cases start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Sorry, I ignored uppercase when write a sample in brief.